# SonarQube coverage report = 0%

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco-maven-plugin

In my pom.xml
Here my new version of pom.xml

```
    <profile>
            <id>coverage</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-Xmx4096m ${jacoco.agent.ut.arg}</argLine>
<!--                            Specific to generate mapping between tests and covered code -->
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>listener</name>
                                    <value>org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-Xmx4096m ${jacoco.agent.it.arg}</argLine>
<!--                            Specific to generate mapping between tests and covered code -->
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>listener</name>
                                    <value>org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
<!--                            Let's put failsafe reports with surefire to have access to tests failures/success reports in sonar -->
                            <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.7.4.201502262128</version>
                        <executions>
<!--                            Prepares a variable, jacoco.agent.ut.arg, that contains the info to be passed to the JVM hosting the code being tested. -->
                            <execution>
                                <id>prepare-ut-agent</id>
                                <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                                    <propertyName>jacoco.agent.ut.arg</propertyName>
                                    <append>true</append>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
<!--                            Prepares a variable, jacoco.agent.it.arg, that contains the info to be passed to the JVM hosting the code being tested. -->
                            <execution>
                                <id>prepare-it-agent</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                                    <propertyName>jacoco.agent.it.arg</propertyName>
                                    <append>true</append>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-jacoco-listeners</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
```

I run this:

```
mvn clean install -Pcoverage org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent
-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
-Djacoco.outputDir=${WORKSPACE}/target
```

And as result success generate file `jacoco.exec` in all folders **target**. Nice.

But in Sonar the coverage is **0%**

[image]

SonarQube use Jenkins's job with the next settings:

```
# Tells SonarQube where the unit tests code coverage reports are
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=**/target/jacoco-ut.exec
```